# Get users location

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, mapkit

So I´ve been working on a task that gets the User's Location.
I worked on this code, it builds and runs nicely on the emulator.
But it does not get my current location.
Am I mssing something? If so, please help!
Here's my code:

[Capture from Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHCyN.jpg)

Comment: Please do not post your code as an image. Please copy and paste the relevant code as text and put it in your question.

Comment: Have you added the Privacy notification text to the Info.plist of your Project?

Comment: I am sorry, since the code was kinda of big, i thought it would be best to post as image. Thank you fro the tip!

Comment: @dasdom Yes i have, I added the "NSLocationWheninUseUsageDescription" and the "NSLocationAlwaysUseUsageDescription"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try changing your didUpdateLocation to this.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()


        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation.coordinate.longitude)

        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)

        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)

        myMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)


    }
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: A better answer would explain what wrong with the OP's code and explain how this code solves the issue.